# how to remake 2d array random unique numbers as 3d?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Random r = new Random();

    int[,] x = new int[10,8];

    int[] temp = new int[x.Length];
    // two dimensional array and i want for three dimensional  array
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++) 
    {
        temp[i] = r.Next(10, 100);
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            if(temp[i] == temp[j]) 
            {
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }  
    for(int i = 0, index = 0; i < x.GetLength(0); i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < x.GetLength(1); j++) 
        {
            x[i, j] = temp[index++]; //two dimensional array unique numbers
            Console.Write(x[i, j] + " ");
        }
    }
```

// i want do it as for 3D and 4 D array unique numbers like that method what can i change or add?

Comment: what do you want to get? in your code you have a x bidimensional array (find a more explicative name for that variable); 
How do you want it to transform in a 3 dimensional array?

Comment: can anyone help me? how can i do for 3d array like that?

Comment: gian paolo : yes i want to transform this code alittle bit like that for 3D array x[i,j,k]   console.write(x[i,j,k]);

Comment: You should post that code in your answer in the first place. Edit it in now so it's properly formatted

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward to do what you're doing for higher dimensions.

Here's my code for 3D:

```
var r = new Random();

int [,,] x = new int[10, 8, 8];

var count =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, x.Rank)
        .Select(y => x.GetLength(y))
        .Aggregate((y, z) => y * z);

var values =
    Enumerable
        .Range(10, count)
        .OrderBy(y => r.Next())
        .ToArray();

var v = 0;
for (var i = x.GetLowerBound(0); i <= x.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    for (var j = x.GetLowerBound(1); j <= x.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        for (var k = x.GetLowerBound(2); k <= x.GetUpperBound(2); k++)
            x[i, j, k] = values[v++];
```

To change it to 4D these lines change:

```
int [,,,] x = new int[10, 8, 8, 12];

// ...

var v = 0;
for (var i = x.GetLowerBound(0); i <= x.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    for (var j = x.GetLowerBound(1); j <= x.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        for (var k = x.GetLowerBound(2); k <= x.GetUpperBound(2); k++)
            for (var l = x.GetLowerBound(3); l <= x.GetUpperBound(3); l++)
                    x[i, j, k, l] = values[v++];
```

Now, in this code I have explicitly called `GetLowerBound` as well as `GetUpperBound` as it is possible in .NET code to have a non-zero based array.

Also, rather than repeatedly re-try getting random numbers until you have unique numbers I simply generated a sequence of unique numbers and then randomly sorted them. That's a little different from your original code. You needed 80 (10 x 8) random values and you were choosing from values ranging from `10` to `99` inclusive. So you had some holes in your numbers.

Comment: thanks for your codes but i only need to correct my code to get a 3d array unique numbers can you transform?

Comment: @badger - I don't understand what you're asking. The first part of my answer works for 3d arrays with unique numbers. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: i understand , but i only need to remake my code to get a 3d array unique numbers, only mine must be remade it;s possible but i don't know how

Comment: @badger - You just want your code fixed? That's what my code does.

Comment: how can i tell you? i need to change my code to get a 3D array unique numbers i don't need other version,

Answer (score 0):

Random r = new Random();

```
        int[,,] x = new int[10, 8, 8];

        int[] temp = new int[x.Length];



        #region one dimensional array unique numbers.

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {

            temp[i] = r.Next(10, 650);

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {

                if (temp[i] == temp[j])
                {

                    i--;

                    break;

                }

            }

        }

        #endregion



        for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < x.GetLength(0); i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < x.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < x.GetLength(2); k++)
                {



                    x[i, j, k] = temp[index++];

                    Console.Write(x[i, j, k] + " ");

                }

                Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }// i think it's correct code i've changed it
```